# Adding Row Numbers To a SELECT Query Result in SQL Server Without use Row_Number() function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i need Add Row Numbers To a SELECT Query without using Row_Number() function.
<strike>and without using user defined functions or stored procedures.</strike>

```
Select (obtain the row number) as [Row], field1, field2, fieldn from aTable
```

UPDATE

i am using SAP B1 DIAPI, to make a query , this system does not allow the use of rownumber() function in the select statement.

Bye.

Comment: And maybe without using any query?

Comment: Would you please post the structure of your table? Do you have any column which would be a reference?

Comment: Can you use the RANK() function?

Comment: @marc_s: Where in my question did I suggest that they are?

Comment: @marc_s: I asked a question to narrow down the problem. We don't know why the row_number function cannot be used .. ah I see that now we do ... anyways, by probing if the Rank function is available, I was trying to determine if it makes sense to further look into it as a solution. I could solve the problem under certain circumstances. But I doubt that it is supported by SAP, so RRUZ is out of luck.

Comment: yeah, if row_number() can't be used, most likely the others won't work either :-( SAP sucks.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work for your particular situation or not, but can you execute this query with a stored procedure?  If so, you can:

A) Create a temp table with all your normal result columns, plus a Row column as an auto-incremented identity.

B) Select-Insert your original query, sans the row column (SQL will fill this in automatically for you)

C) Select * on the temp table for your result set.

Not the most elegant solution, but will accomplish the row numbering you are wanting.

Comment: +1 Finally, use your recommendation, but using a Table variable. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

This query will give you the row_number,

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @table t2 WHERE t2.field <= t1.field) AS row_number,
    field,
    otherField
FROM @table t1
```

but there are some **restrictions** when you want to use it. You have to have one column in your table (in the example it is `field`) which is unique and numeric and you can use it as a reference. For example:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    field INT,
    otherField VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @table(field,otherField) VALUES (1,'a')
INSERT INTO @table(field,otherField) VALUES (4,'b')
INSERT INTO @table(field,otherField) VALUES (6,'c')
INSERT INTO @table(field,otherField) VALUES (7,'d')

SELECT * FROM @table
```

returns

```
field | otherField
------------------
1     | a
4     | b
6     | c
7     | d
```

and

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @table t2 WHERE t2.field <= t1.field) AS row_number,
    field,
    otherField
FROM @table t1
```

returns

```
row_number | field | otherField
-------------------------------
1          | 1     | a
2          | 4     | b
3          | 6     | c
4          | 7     | d
```

This is the solution without functions and stored procedures, but as I said there are the restrictions. But anyway, maybe it is enough for you.

Comment: In my experience, the reference column doesn't need to be numeric, but it does need to be unique.  It also need not be singular; you can use this same method with natural primary keys, for example.  You may also want to use an ORDER BY clause to ensure that the rows are returned in the same order between executions.

Answer (score 1):

RRUZ, you might be able to hide the use of a function by wrapping your query in a View. It would be transparent to the caller. I don't see any other options, besides the ones already mentioned.

Comment: I had already tried, but even so SAP B1 sends an error message.