# How can I add row number for this SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, rows

I have this SQL Server 2008 R2 query

```
SELECT TOP(10)
    *
FROM 
    [T1].dbo.CPU_Benchmarks 
JOIN 
    [T1].dbo.CPU_Slugs ON CPU_Benchmarks.Id = [T1].dbo.CPU_Slugs.BenchmarkId 
                       AND [Approved] = 'true')
ORDER BY 
     [T1].dbo.[CPU_Benchmarks].Overal_Score DESC
```

Comment: You will find a non-elegant method (doesn't use row_number) here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1646726/3854195

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP (10)  
    row_number() over (order by [T1].dbo.[CPU_Benchmarks].Overal_Score DESC) as rn, *
FROM [T1].dbo.CPU_Benchmarks
JOIN [T1].dbo.CPU_Slugs 
   ON CPU_Benchmarks.Id = [T1].dbo.CPU_Slugs.BenchmarkId
  AND [Approved] = 'true'
ORDER BY 
     [T1].dbo.[CPU_Benchmarks].Overal_Score DESC
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to return the RN column as first column?

Comment: yes, just put the `, *` at the end, I update the code

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - is that ORDER BY at the end necessary?

Comment: I don't know, but I need to order by Overal_Score DESC

Comment: In this case may be removed because you already order on the row_number. But not 100% sure will have to test

Comment: @dbagley yes that work without `order by` [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8758c/3)

Comment: It may work now but DO NOT rely on default ordering. If you want rows returned in a certain there is one and only way to ensure that...add an order by. This is the concept that a query will return rows by the clustered index order...it does for awhile most of the time but eventually it will change. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx

Comment: @SeanLange Also I was thinking what would happen if I use two `row_number()` like this [**Case**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32892439/3470178). So new leason learn.

Comment: I think @SeanLange may be making a reference to the general concept of `ORDER BY` and I was asking if it was redundant to have the `ORDER BY` specified using `row_number` and then having *another* `ORDER BY`

Comment: @dbagley I think he has a valid point in the article for trust anything will be stay the same and because the final plan is the same I dont see the harm. Even in [**another**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32892439/3470178) answer I provide i use double `row_number()` so in that case dont know which order will provide.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza  Ok, I agree since it is better to include something that may not be needed than to need it and not have it!

Comment: @dbagley the order by clause is required when using ROW_NUMBER. In this situation you MUST have an order as part of ROW_NUMBER because that defines the order for numbering. The final order by defines how you order the rows in the final output. If you don't care what order the rows are in you can exclude that order by, but I suspect you care. :)

Comment: @SeanLange I understand and it's a good point.  I was thinking in this case and in many others I will want the results ordered such that the row numbers are in sequential order.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT row_number() over(ORDER BY [T1].dbo.[CPU_Benchmarks].Overal_Score DESC) as rn, *
FROM [T1].dbo.CPU_Benchmarks 
JOIN [T1].dbo.CPU_Slugs ON CPU_Benchmarks.Id=[T1].dbo.CPU_Slugs.BenchmarkId 
AND [Approved]='true'
```

You can use the `row_number` function.